# Sorting numbers in a string

Tags: python, string, sorting, python-3.x

I thought it's a very simple problem but all I tried didn't solve this:

Given a string like '12 7 13 1'. How can I sort those number to get 1 7 12 13?

Comment: Had to mention: Python 3.5. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach to do so is this:

1. Split the string and get a vector of numbers
2. Cast from string to integer
3. Sort the numbers

The sample code below in Python does the trick:

```
original_string = '12 3 4 5'
splitted = original_string .split() #splitting
numeric_splitted = [int(numeric_string) for numeric_string in splitted] #casting
numeric_splitted.sort() #sorting
print numeric_splitted # [3,4,5,12] is printed
```

Comment: @YehudaKatz: And once you get more familiar with Python, you'll write this in one line as something like `sorted(int(s) for s in original_string.split())`.

Comment: @user2357112: Or faster/more succinctly: `sorted(map(int, original_string.split()))`. `map` beats genexps/listcomps when the transform function is a built-in implemented at the C layer.